# Accepting input from user using macro

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to accept input from user in x68-64 nasm code.
If I am accepting 16 bytes (eg. 0000000000000001) how much memory should be reserved for variable?

```
 SECTION .bss
    number resb 16 ;16 or 17(16+enter key)?

    %macro read 2  ;is it correct SECTION for defining macro?
    mov rax,00h
    mov rdi,00h ;unsigned int fd. what is correct value for fd?
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdi,%2
    syscall
    %endmacro

SECTION .text
    read number,16 ;16 should be passed as length or 17 considering enter key?
```

Comment: ... why are you writing this in assembly language? Just for fun?

Comment: @zwol trying to understand basics of assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean 16 bytes, not bits.

---

You're making a macro to call [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).  See the man page for the details on what it does.  It just reads bytes from a file descriptor.  If the file descriptor is a tty in canonical mode (not raw mode) with normal terminal settings, then it will be line-buffered.  i.e. the system call will block until a newline or EOF (ctrl-d).  Or until something interrupts it early, making it return `-EINTR`, since you're calling it directly instead of using the glibc wrapper function that takes retries interrupted system calls for you.

See [`stty(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) and [`termios(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for the usual standard-library wrapper on top of the appropriate [tty `ioctl`s](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html).  **TL:DR**: Getting anything other than cooked input is really complicated.  So you don't see "enter key"s, you just see newlines.

It's important to note that if there is more input than will fit in the buffer you passed to `read(2)`, it just reads enough bytes to fill the buffer, and the rest are still pending.  They're not discarded, so another `read` call will get them, not the start of the next line.

---

stdin is always file descriptor zero in POSIX, so `rdi=0` is correct.

The 3rd arg (size) goes in `rdx`, though.  You're putting it in `rdi`, which will probably make your `read(2)` call return with `-EBADF` since your process is unlikely to have anything open on fd 16.

**Run your program under `strace` to see what happens.  (`strace ./a.out`)**

---

Make your buffer as big as the longest line you want your program to accept in one go.  On an interactive tty, `read(2)` will return after one newline, unless the system is so heavily loaded that your process doesn't get woken until a 2nd newline has already been entered.  (e.g. as part of a big paste.)

Comment: that explains a lot . and what about the enter keypress. When to consider it? While reserving or calling macro?

Comment: @Deadpool: when the user presses enter, there will `'\n'` on the tty.  You need your `read` calls to eat them up.  The buffer has to be big enough, *and* the `size` arg to `read(2)` has to be big enough.